# How does the Exchanger supports GC-less Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, garbage-collection, java.util.concurrent

While reading about concurrent api of java, i came to know about `Exchanger` class.

**From Java docs,**

`"A synchronization point at which threads can pair and swap elements within pairs. Each thread presents some object on entry to the exchange method, matches with a partner thread, and receives its partner's object on return. An Exchanger may be viewed as a bidirectional form of a SynchronousQueue. Exchangers may be useful in` ***`applications such as genetic algorithms and pipeline designs.`*** "

I explored and find the following link [The Exchanger & GC-less Java](http://vanillajava.blogspot.in/2011/09/exchange-and-gc-less-java.html)

it says ,

> "The Exchanger class is useful for passing data back and forth between
>   two threads. e.g. Producer/Consumer. It has the property of naturally
>   recycling the data structures used to pass the work and supports
>   GC-less sharing of work in an efficient manner."

How it supports ***`"GC-less sharing of work"`*** ?

Answer (score 1):

Literally it is not supported, it just designed the way you can leverage from using it right way. The benefit will be *GC-less sharing work* as you said. Actaully, it just a programming technique to avoid garbage creation, like temporary objects, exchange objects, etc. The `exchange` method will always return the object you were exchanging. So, there is no need to run GC, cuz you can **reuse the old object** for the next exchange. In other case if you won't reuse the returned object it could not be still `GC-less`.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `LinkedBlockingQueue`s or `ArrayBlockingQueue`s, the `Exchanger` does noch create Nodes or arrays to hold objects. Your will have to create the exchanger though. Downside is, it can hold only one object.